# How to fix error Primary index field ssot__AccountContact__dlm.ssot__Id__c must be included into activation attributes list?

Tags: datacloud

When I try to follow steps here

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/loyalty-management-and-cdp-integration/set-up-loyalty-promotions-with-customer-data-platform

```
Publish the Segment

In the previous unit, Linda created an activation target so she can send segment data to Marketing Cloud. Now it’s time to select the activation target. The data from the segment is sent to this target.

Click , and select Customer Data Cloud.
Click the Segments tab.
Select the Fitness and Sports Enthusiasts segment.
In Activations, click New.
Select Marketing Cloud Bundle as your activation target.
The Activation Membership entity is auto-populated.
Click Continue.
```

I receive an error

```
Primary index field ssot__AccountContact__dlm.ssot__Id__c must be included into activation attributes list.
```

[image]

Does anyone knows why this error happens and how could we fix or avoid it?